# Reference to a computation running on a thread

Tags: multithreading, rust

I want to offload CPU-heavy computations to threads. I want a reference to the computation so I can await the result later in the code. Something like a `Future` but without `async`. Here's roughly what I want:

```rs
let future_result: MyComputationFuture<T> = start_crunching_numbers(params);

// ...do many things, even clone `future_result` if needed

let result: T = future_result.await_computation(); // blocking, can be called multiple times!
```

[edit]: There will be multiple clones of `future_result` throughout the code held by multiple threads so it needs to by `Sync`. The `.await_computation()` function will be called many times on many threads, and it's not possible to know ahead when and where it will be called first. Any attempt to get the result should be blocking unless the computation has finished.

My first attempt was to simply use `RwLock`. Simplified version:

```rs
let resource = std::sync::RwLock::new(0);

{
    // Lock it immediately until the computation is done
    let mut write_lock = resource.write().unwrap();
    std::thread::spawn(move || {
        // wait seven and a half million years
        *write_lock = 42;
    })
};

// Evaluate the result, suspend the thread if it's not ready yet
let result = *resource.read().unwrap();
```

But `RwLockWriteGuard` is `!Send` so this approach won't fly:

```
error[E0277]: `std::sync::RwLockWriteGuard<'_, i32>` cannot be sent between threads safely
```

If I use `parking_lot::RwLock` with the `send_guard` flag, it fails to compile with a different error. `parking_lot::RwLockWriteGuard` apparently has a reference of the `RwLock`:

```rs
error[E0597]: `resource` does not live long enough
let mut write_lock = resource.write();
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
```

Which sync primitive should I be using to solve this and how?

Comment: Why not just return the value from the thread? (Possibly also use a thread pool).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman The `.await_computation()` will be called multiple times, possibly on multiple threads. `JoinHandle::join` can only be called once. I edited the question to be more clear about this criterium.

Comment: And when called multiple times, what do you want the behavior to be? Re-run the computation? Block until ready and clone the result?

Comment: Block until ready and clone the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course Chayim Friedman is right, there is no need for anything else since `spawn` already returns a `JoinHandle` which all you have to do is `join` to wait for the completion of the thread and receive it's return value.
You can still use almost the same `buffer` closure to be able to call it multiple times:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut handle = Some(std::thread::spawn(move || {
        // wait seven and a half million years
        std::thread::sleep_ms(3_000);
        return 42;
    }));

    let mut buffer = None;
    let mut receiver = move || {
        if let Some(handle) = handle.take() {
            buffer = Some(handle.join().ok()?);
        }
        buffer.clone()
    };

    // Evaluate the result, suspend the thread if it's not ready yet
    let result = receiver().unwrap();
    dbg!(result);
    let result = receiver().unwrap();
    dbg!(result);
}
```

Comment: There is no need for a channel, you can return the value from the thread directly.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, this is really close to what I want. The only issue I have now is that `receiver` is not `Sync`, I can't call it from multiple threads. But I guess if I wrap a tuple of `handle` and `buffer` into a `Mutex`, it could work. Or is there a simpler way?

Comment: This solution doesn't work as intended: if you call `receiver()` on the second time while the data is not yet ready (`join()` is waiting) it returns immediately with `None` instead of waiting.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman ah but how would you call `receiver` concurrently, it's a `FnMut` so it requires exclusive access.

Comment: Oh, right. The question is whether @aedm wants to be able to call it concurrently.

Comment: I think the easiest way to sort of achieve that would be to wrap `receiver` in a `Mutex` or similar.

Comment: Based on your answer, I just wrapped this thing in a Mutex and it works wonderfully. Thanks for your help.